Ubuntu 22.04 has crashed and won't boot anymore
everyone! How are you?
This morning I was using Ubuntu and Chrome crashed. All the icons on the taskbar were replaced by a gray symbol and an Ubuntu error appeared, the computer was no longer responding to commands. This had already happened last week and I had restarted normally and it started working again. However, when this happened today I restarted and Ubuntu no longer appears on the boot screen. I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10, they are installed on two different SSDs.
Now I'm using Windows trying to fix Ubuntu, I noticed that Windows updated yesterday to today. I also disabled turn on fast startup and used the commands in cmd to see if I can access Ubuntu:
 bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu yes

 bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

but it didn't work, only Windows 10 appears.
What can I do? Could Ubuntu be corrupted in some way? If so, can I get the important files out of there?

Hard to tell. Also, AFAIK, Windows has no idea what an EXT4 file system is. So do be careful as Windows will happily reformat what it does not understand. I would download an image of Ubuntu onto a USB Drive and boot up using that image (if your computer can boot off a USB Drive). Using that I would inspect the installed copy of Ubuntu. My 1st guess is that you ran out of disk space. But that's just a guess.

I'll try to use an image of Ubuntu onto a USB Drive. Thank you so much!!
